# How can I efficiently detect all blank pages in a PDF?

Tags: pdf

My current solution is opening ["the Page Thumbnails pane on the left"](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/how-would-I-delete-all-blank-pages-at-once-in-a-document-q162915.aspx), and spotting the blank pages. What's a more efficient solution, since [this Jul 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31646450/2670739) post?

I'm not asking about deleting the blank pages automatically; I must check myself if the pages are blank before deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to identify empty pages you could as well use the predefined "Page is empty" Check. This Check shows up in Preflight -> Checks, see attached screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is under **Preflight -> Fixups.** Click **Options** and select **Create new Fixup**. Look for **Remove empty pages fixup** and save it as you wish for easier search later.

Remember that it will delete only those pages that contain no objects at all. If you have white objects or objects without color at all, these pages are not empty and will not be deleted. If you want to delete these pages also, first create a fixup that will delete all empty objects.

[image: Create new Fixup]